# Discordpy TempMute Command

Tags: discord.py

Kind of new to Discordpy moderation commands and would like to know why this code doesn't work,
as I get no errors while trying to run it. it's supposed to temp mute a user for a specific amount of time depending on the unit and if no muted role was created it, creates one.

````
    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self , ctx, user : discord.Member, duration = 0,*, unit = None):
        guild = ctx.guild

        for role in guild.roles:
            if role.name =="Muted":
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await ctx.send("{} Has been muted by {} for {duration}{unit} " .format(member.mention,ctx.author.mention))
                return

                overwrite = discord.PermissionsOverwrite(send_messages=False)
                newRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

                for channel in guild.text_channels:
                    await channel.set_permissions(newRole,overwrite=overwrite)

                await member.add_roles(newRole)
                await ctx.send("{} Has been muted by {} for {duration}{unit}  " .format(member.mention,ctx.author.mention))
                
                if unit == "s":
                        wait = 1 * duration
                        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
                elif unit == "m":
                    wait = 60 * duration
                    await asyncio.sleep(wait)
                await user.remove_roles(roleobject)
                await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: {user} was unmuted")
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

All the code after your return statement is useless, as it will never be executed. Maybe you indented that part too far.
Make a list of the role names and check it through that instead of having a big loop

```
rolenames = {role.name: role for role in guild.roles}
if 'Muted' not in rolenames.keys():
    # Make the new role
    role = new_role_you_created
else:
    role = rolenames['Muted']

# Add the role to the user
await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the code written after a return statement will NEVER be executed, so the last part of your code is unreachable.

You can use *discord.utils.get* to get a role based on the name, insted of looping over every role in the guild.

Then, if there isn't any role under that name, you create a new one (I'm guessing that's the behaviour you're looking for)

```
@commands.command()
async def mute(self , ctx, member : discord.Member, duration: int = 0, unit: str = None):
    guild = ctx.guild

    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if role is None:
        overwrite = discord.PermissionsOverwrite(send_messages=False)
        role = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(role, overwrite=overwrite)
    
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} Has been muted by {ctx.author.mention} for {duration}{unit} ")
    
    if unit == "s":
        wait = 1 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    elif unit == "m":
        wait = 60 * duration
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: {member} was unmuted")
```

You should consider checking if the *unit* is valid before executing the command, because *wait* will not be defined if *unit* is not *s* or *m*, causing the command to raise an error, and the user will be muted forever.

Also, using *asyncio.sleep* in a tempmute command is not recommended. If the bot crashes or is turns off, the user will never be unmuted. Instead, store the tempmutes in a database and check them every X time.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already stated, the code after the return statement won't be executed. So basically the whole command ends if there is a role called "Muted". Also you seem to create a new role called "Muted" if there is a role called Muted in which you disable sending messages. Also I am not sure, if you can't just set the global role permissions to send_messages=True

Do you maybe mean something like this?

```
@commands.command()
    async def mute(self , ctx, user : discord.Member, duration = 0,*, unit = None):
        guild = ctx.guild
        muted_role = None

        for role in guild.roles:
            if role.name =="Muted":
                muted_role = role
        if muted_role == None:
            overwrite = discord.PermissionsOverwrite(send_messages=False)
            muted_role = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                await channel.set_permissions(muted_role,overwrite=overwrite)

        await member.add_roles(muted_role)
        await ctx.send("{} Has been muted by {} for {duration}{unit} " .format(member.mention,ctx.author.mention))

                
        if unit == "s":
            wait = 1 * duration
            await asyncio.sleep(wait)
        elif unit == "m":
            wait = 60 * duration
            await asyncio.sleep(wait)
        await user.remove_roles(roleobject)
        await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: {user} was unmuted")
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: And of course everything less indented than here, 4 spaces less for every line